# JQuery find value of checkbox and check the checkbox based on value

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an array of checkboxes. I need to check the boxes based on the text value for the checkbox.  For examples if I have three checkboxes with the text "Checkbox 01.", "Checkbox 02." and "Checkbox 03." and I have a checkbox called "Select All".  I want to iterate through the array of checkboxes and only check items that contain the word "02." or "03."

I'm not proficient in JQuery, I inherited this, but I took a stab at the code and here is what I tried:

```
$(".rightColumn .SelectAllGroups").on("click", function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(".GroupSelection input:checkbox").each(function (i) {
            //alert("Index of item" + i);
            if (this(i).val.contains("01.") || this(i).val.contains("02.") || this(i).val.contains("03.") ||
                this(i).val.contains("04.") || this(i).val.contains("05.") || this(i).val.contains("06.") || this(i).val.contains("07 .") ||
                this(i).val.contains("08.") || this(i).val.contains("09.") || this(i).val.contains("10.") || this(i).val.contains("11.")) {
                this(i).checked = i;
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".GroupSelection input:checkbox").each(function () {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Just an FYI, the value "07 ." does have a space whereas the others don't.  When I run this I get the error "This is not a function".  The textboxes are created via code.  Here is the result of one textbox

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$mainBody$mainContent$main$newEpisodeForm$NewSnapshot$GroupSelection$groupTypeList$ctl01$groupList$ctl00$groupCheck" type="checkbox" id="mainBody_mainContent_main_newEpisodeForm_NewSnapshot_GroupSelection_groupTypeList_groupList_1_groupCheck_0" isoptionalgroup="true" value="ae37b870-e525-4cce-9315-1e8e4e253483">
<span id="mainBody_mainContent_main_newEpisodeForm_NewSnapshot_GroupSelection_groupTypeList_groupList_1_groupLabel_0">01. First Test</span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Start by checking the errors thrown. There are very noticeable syntax and entity problems in your approach. Suggest you also review the `val()` docs to see how to use it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had an array of values for each of the checkboxes, and they were unique, I put the values in an array and then set the checkbox checked property based on the value from the array.  Here is the code:

```
$(".rightColumn .SelectAllGroups").on("click", function (evt) {
    if (this.checked) {
        
        var initValues = ['ae37b870-e525-4cce-9315-1e8e4e253483',
            '89fcfdee-74df-4304-a343-5b7f46accbb2',
            '38a2cb37-67a3-44a3-bad3-56bd67dedd2e',
            'c5447ffa-f6d2-43bc-9344-07f70fdd1b22',
            '33651165-aa95-45f8-9aa1-63472291543e',
            'ba49da31-8a5a-4453-8186-e679c73f7329',
            'a4ec8b3a-251b-4d8a-865e-8e276811b5ab',
            'cf768b29-68cd-453d-97a3-25cb0404298a',
            '81d1d54a-1618-4bca-a71b-1314733c7edb',
            '160fe561-1963-4b4c-9d61-c0d4a28b4acf',
            '28036de1-7fa9-4a90-8093-72f9a1c4400f']

        $.each(initValues, function (i, val) {

            $("input[value='" + val + "']").prop('checked', true);

        });
    } else {
        $(".GroupSelection input:checkbox").each(function () {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Since the values were unique because they are GUID's, then this worked to pick up the checkboxes I need.

Answer (score 0):

You rather use [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) instead of using contain();

Get element **$(this)** in a var to be sure to use the right element.

You can also get elements from the clicked element by using [prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) (or closest(), nextAll() depending on your project). Like this again, you sure to use the right element to work with.

I commented my code below :

```js
$(".rightColumn .SelectAllGroups").on("click", function () {
  // be sure to get select all input
  let SelectAllGroups = $(this);
  
  // we check if SelectAllGroups is checked
  if ($(SelectAllGroups).is(":checked")) {
    // get closest element with class and then find input checkbox inside
    $(SelectAllGroups).prevAll(".GroupSelection:first").find("input:checkbox").each(function (i) {
      // get checkbox and his val
      let SelectionCheckbox = $(this);
      let SelectionCheckboxVal = SelectionCheckbox.val();
      
      // check if value contain with indexOf
      if (SelectionCheckboxVal.indexOf("01.") != -1 || SelectionCheckboxVal.indexOf("02.") != -1 || SelectionCheckboxVal.indexOf("03 .") != -1 ||  SelectionCheckboxVal.indexOf("04.") != -1) {
        // set prop checked to true
        $(SelectionCheckbox).prop('checked', true);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(SelectAllGroups).prevAll(".GroupSelection:first").find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightColumn">
  <div class="GroupSelection">
    <input type="checkbox" value="01.jqefdqs"> 01.
    <input type="checkbox" value="jqefdqs02."> 02.
    <input type="checkbox" value="jqef03 .dqs"> 03 .
    <input type="checkbox" value="jqef04.dqs"> 04.
    <input type="checkbox" value="05.jqefdqs"> 05.
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="SelectAllGroups"> Select all
</div>
```